# UT010009:Servlet CamelServlet of type class org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet does not implemet jakarta.servlet.Servlet

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, java-17, quay.io

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet CamelServlet of type class org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet does not implement jakarta.servlet.Servlet`

Hi, I am getting the above error when I am trying to build my war file in docker. I am using the below configuration to depoy my war file in the docker

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17-slim as BUILD          
COPY .  /usr/src/myapp/src
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/myapp/src/pom.xml clean install

FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:27.0.0.Final-jdk17
#rest of the docker configuration
```

I could able to run the war file in the local jboss server 7.3. But only in docker I am facing the issue.
Could anyone please help me how can I deploy my war file in docker with what version of jboss/wildfly

I have tried changing the org.apache.camel version to the latest version. After doing that I am facing the other issues as below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010012: Listener class class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener must implement at least one listener interface
```

And after changing the org.apache.camel version I could not even run the war file in local jboss 7.3 version also.

Struggling with the issues from weeks. Solution for this issue highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? My assumption is 3.x which is Jakarta EE 8 so you'd need to use WildFly 26 not 27.